# How can I check if a javascript property is true even if it undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
       if (subject.current == true) {
            return;
        }
```

If `subject.current` is `undefined` I would like it to continue but it seems like it fails when I check for true.  How can I make it so it does not error out if current is not defined?

Comment: add `|| subject.current == undefined`

Comment: javascript is funny in this way, "undefined" is essentially the same as if you were to speak some word to me that wasn't in my vocabulary and I would have to ask you to define it for me to understand what you were saying to me.  javascript also has null, which is hard for me to give an example of, but null is essentially a value that indicates the "absence of known value", it's kind of like a blank check I guess, until you place a dollar amount on the check it's really a placeholder for a currently undetermined value.

Comment: Hello,  Maybe my question was not clear but I need the code to continue and not do a return if the subject.current is undefined.  Sorry if my question was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this like below:

```
if (subject && subject.current == true) {
      return;
}
```

1. If the `subject` itself `undefined / null` the below code execution will continues. `return` statement will not be executed. This avoids 'undefined' error.
2. If the `subject` has property `subject.current` and if that is true then `return` statement will execute. until other wise if any one condition fails the code which is below the `if statement` will be executed.

Hope this is what your expectation is.....

Comment: Hello. What I need is if the subject.current is not defined then I need the code to continue. In other words not do a return. Maybe I am confused but it seems like every answer causes the code to return. Can you check if this is the case with your answer also. Thanks.

Comment: In that case you just need to put condition `&&` `and` instead of `||` OR. See my updated code.

Answer (score 5):

If it is undefined then it isn't true. You need to check for both possible conditions with the or operator.

```
if (typeof subject.current === "undefined" || subject.current == true)
```

Comment: Hello. What I need is if the subject.current is not defined then I need the code to continue. In other words not do a return. Maybe I am confused but it seems like every answer causes the code to return. Can you check if this is the case with your answer also. Thanks.

Comment: If you want it to bypass the `if` then do nothing. Your original code will just work. (It would be different is `subject` wasn't defined, but you are asking about `current`).

Answer (score 2):

```
if (subject.current != undefined && subject.current == true) {
    return;
}
```

This should check if the property has been set or if it is true else it will continue

Comment: Hello. What I need is if the subject.current is not defined then I need the code to continue. In other words not do a return. Maybe I am confused but it seems like every answer causes the code to return. Can you check if this is the case with your answer also. Thanks.

Comment: Hi I modified my answer to only perform the check for .current if the object is defined . Ff it is undefined it will continue with the code and ignore the check for true

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way, **slightly reduced**:

```
if ((subject||{}).current){
   //do something
}

//Strict comparison
if ((subject||{}).current === true){
   //do something
}
```

Comment: Hello. What I need is if the subject.current is not defined then I need the code to continue. In other words not do a return. Maybe I am confused but it seems like every answer causes the code to return. Can you check if this is the case with your answer also. Thanks.